# How to Pivot SQL Server Table with multiple column values?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

How do I get the expected result using the SQL `PIVOT` function. I tried the below query to do this but I am getting only one record in the `NAME` column.

Sample Data:

```
    SNO       TYPE     ENTRY            
    1         Name     Andy         
    1         Name     Kevin            
    1         Active   Yes                   
    1         Value    50           
    2         Name     Andy         
    2         Name     Julia            
    2         Active   No           
    2         Value    45
```

Expected Result:

```
   SNO    NAME        ACTIVE    VALUE       
   1    Andy, Kevin    Yes       50          
   2    Andy, Julia    No        45
```

Query I tried:

```
            select SNO,Name,Active,Value 
            from 
                (
                select * from tbl1
                ) as PivotData

                Pivot 
                (
                max(ENTRY) for TYPE in([Name],[Active],[Value])
                ) as Pivoting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ACTIVE and VALUE do not have multiple values.  We just exclude NAME from the PIVOT and resolve it via the standard XML STUFF

**Example**

```
Select SNO
      ,Name  = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +Entry From @YourTable Where SNO=Pvt.SNO and [TYPE]='Name' For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
      ,Active
      ,Value 
 From   YourTable A
 Pivot ( max(ENTRY) for TYPE in (Active,Value) ) Pvt
```

**Returns**

```
SNO Name        Active  Value
1   Andy,Kevin  Yes     50
2   Andy,Julia  No      45
```

Comment: That's Awesome John! Although my original query was too complicated and it had 15 columns with multiple values like this one and the solution worked for me perfectly. I Saved a lot of time. Tons of thanks for this.

Comment: @Andy Always happy to help  :)